# ClangTool how to get location of template parameters in variable declaration?

Tags: c++, clang

I am using a `RecursiveASTVisitor` to capture variable declarations. For templates, such as the one below, how can I use clang tool to get the location in the source code for each of the parameters?

```cpp
TMyTemplate<t1, t2> foo;
```

**Attempt 1:** create a `VisitVarDecl` visitor

Using this approach I am able to identify whether the variable is a template and get the type as `clang::TemplateSpecializationType`. It allows me to iterate over the arguments using `getArg`, however the the returning type (`TemplateArgument`) does not implement `getLocation`.

```cpp
virtual bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *var) {
        const TemplateSpecializationType *ts = var->getType()->getAs<TemplateSpecializationType>();
        if( ts != nullptr ) {
            for(uint32_t i=0; i< ts->getNumArgs(); i++) {
                TemplateArgument arg = ts->getArg(i);
                // I want to get arg.getLocation() - but no getLocation in TemplateArgument.
            }
        }

}
```

I tried converting the type `TemplateArgument` to `TemplateArgumentLoc` but any approach leads me a dummy location (i.e.: always return line 1 and column 1, or even seg faults).

**Attempt 2:** using `VisitVarTemplateSpecializationDecl` visitor

In Clang the type `VarTemplateSpecializationDecl` allows me to get the template parameters as `clang::TemplateArgumentListInfo`. This type seems more convenient as it we can get  `TemplateArgumentLoc` with the function `getArgumentArray`.

The issue is that the template declaration does not trigger this visitor. I don't quite understand the reason.

**Attempt 3:** get `VarDecl` as `TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc`

I also tried getting the `VarDecl` as `TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc` but it fails.

```cpp
TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc loc = var->getTypeSourceInfo()->getTypeLoc().getAs<TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc>();
```

**Quick references**

- I am using the reference code from this [blog](https://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example/), here is the [full code](https://github.com/kevinaboos/LibToolingExample/blob/master/Example.cpp).
- [clang::VarTemplateSpecializationDecl](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarTemplateSpecializationDecl.html)
- [clang::TemplateArgumentListInfo](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TemplateArgumentListInfo.html)
- [clang::TemplateArgumentLoc](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TemplateArgumentLoc.html)
- [clang::TemplateArgument](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TemplateArgument.html)
- [clang::TemplateSpecializationType](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TemplateSpecializationType.html)

**Troublesome test case**

The solution provided by Valeriy works almost perfectly. His solution can capture the location for the variable declaration `TemplateType<ABC, XYZ> Decl;` but it fails if I explicit the namespace: `FOO::TemplateType<ABC, XYZ> Decl;`.

Here is a simple test case. The variable `Decl` is found in his solution but `Decl2` is not. The cast `auto Specialization = DeclarationTypeLoc.getAs<clang::TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc>()` fails for some reason (returns nullptr).

```cpp
namespace FOO {

class ABC {};
class XYZ {};

template <class T, class U> class TemplateType {};

}

using namespace FOO;



int main() {
    TemplateType<ABC, XYZ> Decl;
    FOO::TemplateType<ABC, XYZ> Decl2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first attempt was the closest to what you need. The node you are looking for is `VarDecl` and it's type location. `VarTemplateSpecializationDecl` is a variable template ([C++14 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template)) specialization.

> Represents a variable template specialization, which refers to
>   a variable template with a given set of template arguments.
>
> Variable template specializations represent both explicit
>   specializations of variable templates, as in the example below, and
>   implicit instantiations of variable templates.

Clang makes a distinction between types and type locations. **Type** is more of an abstract entity, while **TypeLoc** represents an actual entrance of a type in the source code. When you write type `A` in your code many times, it's all different **TypeLoc**s, but the same **Type**.

Here is an example of how to get **TypeLoc** for your declaration:

```cpp
bool VisitVarDecl(clang::VarDecl *Decl) {
  auto DeclarationTypeLoc = Decl->getTypeSourceInfo()->getTypeLoc();

  if (auto Specialization =
          DeclarationTypeLoc.getAs<clang::TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc>()) {

    for (auto i : llvm::seq<unsigned>(0, Specialization.getNumArgs())) {
      auto ArgumentLoc = Specialization.getArgLoc(i);
      auto &SM = Context.getSourceManager();
      llvm::errs() << ArgumentLoc.getLocation().printToString(SM) << "\n";
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Running this code on the following snippet

```cpp
// main.cpp

template <class T, class U> class TemplateType {};

class ABC {};
class XYZ {};

int main() {
  TemplateType<ABC, XYZ> Decl;
  return 0;
}
```

produces this result:

```
.../main.cpp:9:16
.../main.cpp:9:21
```

**NOTE 1**: depending on the version of Clang you might use not `Decl->getTypeSourceInfo()->getTypeLoc()`, but `Decl->getTypeLoc()`.

**NOTE 2**: small tip - don't make visitor functions virtual. Clang's visitors are [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

---

### UPDATE 1

For the updated test snippet, **TypeLoc** of the declaration is not exactly **TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc**, but a wrapper around it. Getting to it manually can be troublesome and error-prone, so it's better to implement it in terms of Clang's traversers.

Here is the updated code (please, note that **SpecificationArgumentVisitor** is a nested class *inside* of your main visitor):

```cpp
class SpecificationArgumentVisitor
    : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<SpecificationArgumentVisitor> {
public:
  SpecificationArgumentVisitor(clang::ASTContext &Context)
      : SM(Context.getSourceManager()) {}

  bool VisitTemplateSpecializationTypeLoc(
      clang::TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc Specialization) {
    for (auto i : llvm::seq<unsigned>(0, Specialization.getNumArgs())) {
      auto ArgumentLoc = Specialization.getArgLoc(i);
      llvm::errs() << ArgumentLoc.getLocation().printToString(SM) << "\n";
    }
    return true;
  }

private:
  SourceManager &SM;
};

bool VisitVarDecl(clang::VarDecl *Decl) {
  SpecificationArgumentVisitor ArgumentVisitor(Context);
  ArgumentVisitor.TraverseDecl(Decl);
  return true;
}
```

For the new test snippet:

```cpp
// main.cpp

namespace FOO {
class ABC {};
class XYZ {};

template <class T, class U> class TemplateType {};
} // namespace FOO

using namespace FOO;

int main() {
  TemplateType<ABC, XYZ> Decl;
  FOO::TemplateType<ABC, XYZ> Decl2;
  return 0;
}
```

it produces the following output:

```
.../main.cpp:13:16
.../main.cpp:13:21
.../main.cpp:14:21
.../main.cpp:14:26
```

**NOTE 3**: It is a nested **RecursiveASTVisitor** because in the original problem you wanted to traverse template specializations only for types in variable declarations. If you want it to work for every case, just use this visit function and only one visitor.

I hope this information was useful. Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: By the way, I believe you forgot to `return true` at the end of the `VisitVarDecl` function.

Comment: @rkioji oh, yes. I forgot to copy it... *whoops* :) I'm glad it helped

Comment: There is an specific case that fails casting to `TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc`. This happens when we explicit the namespace behind the type (e.g.: `std::vector`) rather than (`vector`) if we had previously stated `using namespace`. I updated my question with the troublesome test case. Do you have any starting point which I can look for?

Comment: I didn't check it in actual code, but I expect to find an `ElaboratedTypeLoc` wrapper around `TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc` in your code snippet.

Comment: I have updated the answer to work in the most generic case. I hope it helps!